# What version of Java do I have to install?

Tags: java, linux, jsp, ide, debian

What version of Java do I have to install to be able to develop JSP in Debian? There are different version on the Oracle site. What version is needed? Java SE?

Comment: Debian does have packages for Java...

Answer (score 4):

You only need [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html) from the oracle's site. This will provide the standard java API. To get the JSP implementation, you will be needing a standard web container like [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). This will enable you to develop JSP based applications. To develop JSP based applications only, these two will be enough.

However, if you need to use full Java EE stack (JSP, JNDI, EJB etc.) then you will need more than those two. In that case you should use a full fledged Java EE Application Server like [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/), [JBOSS](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/) etc. These will provide the implementation of the Full Java EE specification.

So for only JSP based applications, use JDK + a standard web container ( like tomcat).

To use full Java EE Stack, use JDK + an application server (like GlassFish, JBOSS etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any version, but JDK 1.5 or above, I would suggest you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to an OS.
You should download at least 1.6 not due to OS but due to the fact that older versions are becoming deprecated.
Besides the missing features I believe 1.5 is no longer supported by Oracle except in special cases

Unless you are asking about Java SE or Java EE.
Either is fine.The difference is that for Java SE you need to include some extra jars to be able to compile certain classes related to servlets.
For Java EE you just get extra stuff you'll not need.
Check here for a quick explanation [Java Versions](http://brianwill.net/blog/2007/03/03/a-brief-explanation-of-java-versions/)